# AngularJS: $routeParams to work within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I know this is easy, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this.

I need to do the API call within a service so that those variables can be accessed between two separate controllers.

The problem I am having is I can't access $routeParams (which I need for the get) within the service. I can't figure out know how to pass $routeParams from the controller to the service.

```
    app.controller('Main', ['$scope', 'Page', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, Page, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.Page = Page;
}]);

app.controller('Pages', ['$scope', 'Page', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, Page, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.Page = Page.posts;
}]);

app.factory('Page', ['$routeParams', '$http', function($routeParams, $http) {
    var posts = function posts() {
        $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?filter[name]='+ $routeParams.slug).success(function(res){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res) );
        }); 
    };
            var description = '';
            var title = '';
            return {
                title: function () { return title; },
                setTitle: function (newTitle) { title = newTitle; },
                description: function () { return description; },
                setDescription: function (newDescription) { description = newDescription; },
                posts
        }; 
}]);
```

Comment: From a separation of concerns point of view, I would say to instead pass an object with the extracted $routeParams parameters within it. This would keep view layer concerns from bleeding into your service layer.

Answer (score 0):

**factory :**

```
app.factory('Page', ['$http', function($http) {
        var _posts = function posts(param) {
          return  $http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?filter[name]='+ param);
        };
                var description = '';
                var title = '';
                return {
                    title: function () { return title; },
                    setTitle: function (newTitle) { title = newTitle; },
                    description: function () { return description; },
                    setDescription: function (newDescription) { description = newDescription; },
                    posts : _posts
            }; 
    }]);
```

**Controller :**

```
app.controller('Pages', ['$scope', 'Page', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, Page, $routeParams, $http) {
    Page.posts($routeParams.slug).then(function success(response) {
       $scope.Page = response.data;
}, function error(reason) {
// do something
});
}]);
```

please note that `success` is deprecated in newer versions of Angular. I have updated the code with `then`

Comment: cool. plz mark is as ans and vote up so that it may help others.